# Split Matrix and Use Mesh to Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mesh

I'm a newbie in Matlab and this community. Recently I'd like to use a 3*3 matrix with x,y,z in each row to plot a 3D graph:

```
Array=reshape(1:9,3,3)
M=reshape(Array,[],3)
A=M(:,1)
B=M(:,2)
C=M(:,3)
mesh(A,B,C)
```

Now the dialogue keep showing "Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector" for mesh command.
Is there any wrong about A,B,C matrix?

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. Have you read the documentation for [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) to see what form the inputs must take for that syntax? Are you sure you want a mesh and not a 3d plot with [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html)?

Comment: Actually this is a simplified matrix. The original matrix contains thousands of rows regarding location information(latitude, longitude, height), so it is better to use mesh to draw 3D geometry with different height color

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. You still need to read the documentation for the functions you're trying to use and pass the correct inputs.

Comment: @excaza Thanks for your reply. I know the input of mesh is matrix, but I don't know why A, B, C can't satisfy matrix requirement here.

Comment: `A`, `B`, and `C` in your example are defined as vectors. `C` needs to be a matrix. From the documentation that I've already asked you to read twice: `mesh(X,Y,Z) draws a wireframe mesh with color determined by Z, so color is proportional to surface height. If X and Y are vectors, length(X) = n and length(Y) = m, where [m,n] = size(Z). In this case, (X(j), Y(i), Z(i,j)) are the intersections of the wireframe grid lines; X and Y correspond to the columns and rows of Z, respectively.`

Comment: It is pretty annoying, I agree with that. However, mesh is used to create a mesh grid and not to plot points as a mesh. I suppose the reason is that mesh itself cannot determine the size. The mesh does not necessarily need to be square.